# Constructors from extended class in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

I'm having some trouble with a hw assignment.  In one assignment, we had to create a Person class.  Mine was:

```
public class Person
{
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String telephone;
    String email;

    public Person()
    {
       firstName = "";
       lastName = "";
       telephone = "";
       email = "";
    }

    public Person(String firstName)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName, String telephone, String email) 
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.telephone = telephone;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName()
    {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName)
    {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getTelephone()
    {
        return telephone;
    }

    public void setTelephone(String telephone)
    {
        this.telephone = telephone;
    }

    public String getEmail()
    {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email)
    {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object otherObject)
    {
        // a quick test to see if the objects are identical
        if (this == otherObject) {
            return true;
        }

        // must return false if the explicit parameter is null
        if (otherObject == null) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!(otherObject instanceof Person)) {
            return false;
        }

        Person other = (Person) otherObject;
        return firstName.equals(other.firstName) && lastName.equals(other.lastName) &&
            telephone.equals(other.telephone) && email.equals(other.email);
    }

    public int hashCode() 
    {
        return 7 * firstName.hashCode() +
            11 * lastName.hashCode() + 
            13 * telephone.hashCode() + 
            15 * email.hashCode();
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return getClass().getName() + "[firstName = " + firstName + '\n'
                                    + "lastName = " + lastName + '\n'
                                    + "telephone = " + telephone + '\n'
                                    + "email = " + email + "]";
    }
}
```

Now we have to create a Loan class that uses Person as an attribute, and then extend that Loan class.  My Loan class is:

```
public abstract class Loan
{
    public void setLoanId(int nextId)
    {
        loanId = nextId;
        nextId++;
    }

    public int getLoanId()
    {
        return loanId;
    }

    public void setInterestRate(double interestRate)
    {
        this.interestRate = interestRate;
    }

    public double getInterestRate()
    {
        return interestRate;
    }

    public void setLoanLength(int loanLength)
    {
        this.loanLength = loanLength;
    }

    public int getLoanLength()
    {
        return loanLength;
    }

    public void setLoanAmount(double loanAmount)
    {
        this.loanAmount = loanAmount;
    }

    public double getLoanAmount(double loanAmount)
    {
        return loanAmount;
    }

    public void printPayments()
    {
        double monthlyInterest;
        double monthlyPrincipalPaid;
        double newPrincipal;
        int paymentNumber = 1;
        double monthlyInterestRate = interestRate / 1200;
        double monthlyPayment = loanAmount * (monthlyInterestRate) / 
                                (1 - Math.pow((1 + monthlyInterestRate),( -1 * loanLength)));

        // amortization table
        while (loanAmount != 0) {
            monthlyInterest = loanAmount * monthlyInterestRate;
            monthlyPrincipalPaid = monthlyPayment - monthlyInterest;
            newPrincipal = loanAmount - monthlyPrincipalPaid;
            loanAmount = newPrincipal;

            System.out.println("Payment Number | Interest | Principal | Loan Balance");
            System.out.printf("%d, %.2f, %f, %f", paymentNumber++, monthlyInterest, newPrincipal, loanAmount);
        }
    }
    /*
    //method to print first payment
    public double getFirstPayment()
    {
    }

    method to print last payment
    public double getLastPayment()
    {
    }*/

    private Person client;
    private int loanId;
    private double interestRate;
    private int loanLength;
    private double loanAmount;
    private static int nextId = 1;

}
```

And then extended the Loan class with CarLoan class, there is a function prototype of:

```
public CarLoan(Person client, double vehiclePrice, double downPayment, double salesTax,
                    double interestRate, CAR_LOAN_TERMS length)
```

I'm confused on how I use the Person constructor from the superclass.  I cannot necessarily do

```
super(client);
```

in my constructor which is what the book did with some primitive types in their example.  Not sure what the correct thing to do is...  Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Comment: Does the CarLoan class extend Person?

Comment: Sorry, Loan extends Person, and Carloan extends Loan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CarLoan should not extend Person. That makes no sense since a CarLoan can't be a Person.

But Person can be a class variable in the CarLoan class.

```
public class CarLoan {

  private Person client;
  private double vehiclePrice;

  public CarLoan(Person client, double vehiclePrice, double downPayment, double salesTax, double interestRate, CAR_LOAN_TERMS length) {

    this.client = client;
    this.vehiclePrice = vehiclePrice;
    ..
  }
}
```

Comment: I think client should be a protected member of Loan.

Comment: @NomeN: If the client was declared in Loan, then it should have been protected. But it doesn't add any value in this case when no class extends from CarLoan.

Comment: The OP mentions in his post that Person should be an attribute of Loan, i.o.w. there should be a field of type Person in Loan. Because you need access to this field from CarLoan to set it, you'll need either get/set methods for this field or make it protected.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to be using [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) in stead of inheritance.

In plain english, a CarLoan *has a* client (of type Person). A CarLoan itself is not a Person (which inheritance would suggest).

So you should do what Espen suggests (composition), in stead of `CarLoan extends Person` (inheritance).

A possibly legit use of inheritance would be:

```
class Waiter extends Person {
    String employeeId;

    // A waiter is a person with some extra information
    public Waiter(String firstName, String lastName, String telephone, 
                  String email, String employeeId) {
      super(firstName, lastName, telephone, email); // must be first
      this.employeeId = employeeId;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `CarLoan` is to extend `Person`, then `Person` becomes the superclass of `CarLoan`.

From within the constructor of `CarLoan` you must always call one of the `Person` constructors via the `super` keyword before any other processing takes place.

However, it seems to me very much like you must be confused, as your prototype method passes an instance of `Person` to `CarLoan`. Further, I cannot see why a class called `CarLoan` would extend a person.